# vue js jquery switcher

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm trying to bind an array of checkboxes while using a jQuery plugin called switcher (which is also wrapped by the Pixel Admin theme).
My problem is that it's not initializing the plugin.

`HTML`

```html
<div v-for="partnerType in partnerTypes" class="panel-body">
    {{ partnerType.name }}
    <span class="pull-right">
        <input name="types[]" type="checkbox"
            value="{{partnerType.id}}"
            v-checkbox
            v-model="checkedPartnerTypes"
            v-on:change="updatePartnershipPartnerType(partnerType)">
    </span>
</div>

<script src="/javascripts/custom/directives/checkbox.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/custom/companies/show.js"></script>
```

`checkbox.js`

```
Vue.directive('checkbox', function(value) {
    $(this.el).switcher({
        theme: 'modern',
        on_state_content: '',
        off_state_content: ''
    });

    if(value)
        $(this.el).addClass('checked');
    else
        $(this.el).removeClass('checked');
});
```

In the `show.js` file, I basically have a `checkedPartnerTypes: []` array, which I update initially and after every request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directive is never actually updating because you're not passing a value to `v-checkbox`. That shorthand you're using is for when you just need the `update` method.

You might just want to do something like this in `bind` since the plugin appears to detect if the element is selected or not.

```
Vue.directive('checkbox', {
  bind: function () {
    $(this.el).switcher();
  }
});
```

This way it'll just be applied once.

Comment: I had to manually update its state through jQuery (also adding the checked class to the parent element). What made the difference, though, was that I wasn't telling the directive whether the checkbox was selected or not, so I ended up just passing its state as a boolean with `v-checkbox="typeIsChecked(partnerType.id)"` and it's now working perfectly! Thanks.